# What is the scope of %union in yacc

Tags: yacc, bison

I'm a little confused by %union in yacc. Is a unique union defined for every single token or is there one global union? I'm trying to decide if I need to make everything in the union a list and just append data to the proper type or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a separate `%union` object for each token. For example, a typical rule would be something like:

```
expr: value '+' value:     { $$ = $1 + $3; }
```

In this case, `$$`, `$1` and `$3` each represents a separate object of the type you defined in the `%union` statement. Typically, you'd have something like:

```
%union { 
    int int_val;
    /* ... */
}
```

and:

```
%type <int_val> value expr
```

which would mean that the `value` and `expr` rules produce %union objects in which the `int_val` member is valid.